# django celery vs multithreading vs asyncio

Tags: python, django, multithreading, celery, python-asyncio

I have a Django application that allows users to upload a file and my application will convert the file to the user's specifications. Currently, if multiple users try to convert files at the same time, the process will go something like this

```
Process user 1s files
converting...
done
Process user 2s files
converting...
done
```

It's essentially acting as a queue. Clearly, this is inefficient when multiple users are trying to convert files. I have looked into things like multithreading, celery, asyncio, etc. I can't seem to pick out the differences between the 3. What is the difference and which would be best so users on my site can convert files without waiting for other users' files to finish? Thanks :)

Comment: how are you running Django? Gunicorn or other? If Gunicorn you can add a worker https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html?highlight=workers#asyncio-workers

Comment: @AMG Never heard of Gunicorn. Will check it out. I am running the Django project locally.

Comment: with something like `python manage runserver`?

Comment: yes. That is correct.

Comment: at time of writing django support for async views exist, but from the examples I've seen tasks tend to complete before the view is exited. Among Celery's (or channels) abilities is to hand off tasks to background for processing which can increase the apparent speed but won't be rendered back through browser (page reload or other to check on status for the batch or some other method). Much of the efficiency will depend on what you doing to convert the files.